# Implementing MAP (Bluetooth Message Access Protocol) in an Android wearable

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have a wearable running Android OS. I want to make it possible to pair mobile phones(Android+iOS) via Bluetooth and see all the notifications over MAP. Could somebody help me on what I need to implement on my wearable to achieve this? From what I understood MAP services are enabled by default with modern Android and iOS phones. I believe this is the same technology used by connected devices in smart homes and car stereo. Should the goal be to implement a GATT client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take Android native MAP client [MAP client](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/bluetooth/+/android-cts-8.1_r8/src/android/bluetooth/client/map). It uses OBEX (Rfcomm connection). When notifications are enabled your MNS server will receive them.
But I am not sure if such solution will work if your OS already has a working MAP client.